# Regex for parsing Facebook Open Graph meta tag

Tags: regex, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm trying to pull the og:title attribute from a Bing Local page for a Windows Store app.
There is no HTML parser for WinRT and C++/CX, so I've resorted to using a regex to grab the tag, then an XML parser to pull out relevant attributes.

This is what the tag looks like.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Location Name"/>
```

I'm using the following regex to pull out the tag from the HTML, but whenever the content attribute has a space in it, it fails to find a match.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="[\s\S]*"/>
```

So, my regex will work for McDonald's, but not for Jack In The Box.

What do I need to do to get the entire title?

Comment: did you tried something like that: `[^"]*`

Answer (score 3):

This is one of my open graph regex queries which match most things with specific problems in content, but those are rare and I'd rather have a more readable regex

```
<meta [^>]*property=[\"']og:title[\"'] [^>]*content=[\"']([^'^\"]+?)[\"'][^>]*>
```

But I do come across some times where the content comes before property so I also run this

```
<meta [^>]*content=[\"']([^'^\"]+?)[\"'] [^>]*property=[\"']og:image[\"'][^>]*>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a space to the regex. `[ \s\S]*`

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: OpenGraph.io is a commercial product I work on and support.

Unfortunately, any regex you come up with is going to be hit or miss.  If you end up needing to do this you can use the API available at http://www.opengraph.io/

One of its major benefits is that it will infer information like the title or description (if you end up needing it) from the content on the page if OpenGraph tags don't exist.

To get information about a site use: 
`GET https://opengraph.io/api/1.0/site/<URL encoded site URL>`

Which will return something like:

```
{
   "hybridGraph": {
      "title": "Google",
      "description": "Search the world's information...",
      "image": "http://google.com/images/srpr/logo9w.png",
      "url": "http://google.com",
      "type": "site",
      "site_name": "Google"
   },
   "openGraph": {..}
   "htmlInferred": {..}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.